# Chrome Extension: Manifest is not valid JSON

Tags: json, google-chrome-extension

Thanks for reading my question. 
It says that Manifest is not valid JSON. Line: 31, column: 3, Syntax error. 
And highlights the colon after "permissions".

```
{
  "manifest_version": "2.0",

  "name": "Getting started example",
  "description": "This extension shows a Google Image search result for the current page",
  "version": "1.0",

  "page_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "popup": "https://google.ca",
    "default_title": "Click here!"

  },

  // "background": {
  //   // "scripts": ["eventPage.js"],
  //   "persistent": false
  // },

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*"],
      "css": ["core.css"],
      "js": ["core.js"],
      "run_at": "document_end",
      "all_frames": true
    }
  ]

  "permissions": [
    // "tabs",
    // "webRequest",
    "activeTab",
    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Not the indicated line, but `"manifest_version": "2.0",` should be `"manifest_version": 2,`

Comment: @Teepeeemm Thx! I have fixed it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a "," After the content_scripts array